# Trigger event in Jest Test does not call Method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, triggers, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am currently writing tests for my Vue application. I have a button which calls a logout function. I just want to test if the function gets called when the button gets clicked.

I have tried to mock the function with jest.fn() but i cant get it to work. I also tried to actually trigger the method and put a console.log in the method but that log did not get called. What am I doing wrong?

this is my wrapper setup:

```
let wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
    Vue.use(Vuetify);
    Vue.prototype.$router = new VueRouter();
    wrapper = shallowMount(Navigation);
});

afterEach(() => {
    wrapper.destroy();
});
```

```
it('should call logout function on button click', function() {
        let submitLogoutMock = jest.fn();
        wrapper.vm.submitLogout = submitLogoutMock;

        wrapper
            .find('#logout-button')
            .trigger('click');

        expect(submitLogoutMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

I expect the mocked method to be called but actually i get an error saying:

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.
```

Comment: Verify whether your component is listening for a custom `click` event or a native one, because right now it looks like you're triggering a native `click` event.

Comment: `<v-btn icon id="logout-button" @click.native="logout">`
I tried researching again and added the `.native` and now my test works.. can you explain why i dont really understand the difference between a native and a normal click

Comment: `.native` modifier listens for native DOM events, such as a `click` event emitted by a `button` element. By default when you use `v-on` or the`@` shorthand vue listens for [custom events](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html), ones you trigger using `$emit`.

Answer (score 2):

When using `shallowMount` the methods of component should be stubbed. You can achieve this while creating the wrapper or by using `setMethods()`.

You only need to change your unit test:

```
  it('should call logout function on button click', () => {
    const submitLogoutMock = jest.fn();
    wrapper.setMethods({ submitLogout: submitLogoutMock });

    wrapper.find('#logout-button').trigger('click');

    expect(submitLogoutMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```